# Dataset query for upper levels

Tags: dataset

I have the following data set:

```
dataset = Dataset[{
<|"County" -> "ALACHUA", "Adjacent_County" -> "BRADFORD", 
 "City" -> "BROOKER"|>,
<|"County" -> "ALACHUA", "Adjacent_County" -> "BRADFORD", 
 "City" -> "HAMPTON"|>,
<|"County" -> "ALACHUA", "Adjacent_County" -> "BRADFORD", 
 "City" -> "LAWSEY"|>,
<|"County" -> "ALACHUA", "Adjacent_County" -> "BRADFORD", 
 "City" -> "STARKE"|>,
<|"County" -> "ALACHUA", "Adjacent_County" -> "COLUMBIA", 
 "City" -> "LAKECITY"|>,
<|"County" -> "ALACHUA", "Adjacent_County" -> "GILCHRIST", 
 "City" -> "FANNINGSPRINGS"|>,
<|"County" -> "ALACHUA", "Adjacent_County" -> "GILCHRIST", 
 "City" -> "TRENTON"|>,
<|"County" -> "ALACHUA", "Adjacent_County" -> "LEVY", 
 "City" -> "CEDARKEY"|>,
<|"County" -> "ALACHUA", "Adjacent_County" -> "LEVY", 
 "City" -> "CHIEFLAND"|>,
<|"County" -> "ALACHUA", "Adjacent_County" -> "LEVY", 
 "City" -> "FANNINGSPRINGS"|>,
<|"County" -> "ALACHUA", "Adjacent_County" -> "LEVY", 
 "City" -> "WILLISTON"|>,
<|"County" -> "ALACHUA", "Adjacent_County" -> "MARION", 
 "City" -> "BELLEVIEW"|>,
<|"County" -> "ALACHUA", "Adjacent_County" -> "MARION", 
 "City" -> "DUNNELLON"|>,
<|"County" -> "ALACHUA", "Adjacent_County" -> "MARION", 
 "City" -> "OCALA"|>,
<|"County" -> "ALACHUA", "Adjacent_County" -> "PUTNAM", 
 "City" -> "CRESCENTCITY"|>,
<|"County" -> "ALACHUA", "Adjacent_County" -> "PUTNAM", 
 "City" -> "PALATKA"|>,
<|"County" -> "ALACHUA", "Adjacent_County" -> "UNION", 
 "City" -> "LAKEBUTLER"|>}];
```

What Mathematica command should I use so that if I query: "FANNINGSPRINGS"; the evaluation of the command returns: `{"GILCHRIST", "LEVY"}`. This means that Fanning Springs is a city located at two counties; namely Gilchrist and Levy, that are adjacent to Alachua County.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `GroupBy` to do this:

```
dataset[GroupBy["City"] /* "FANNINGSPRINGS", All, "Adjacent_County"]
```

> [image]

Using `Normal` to get the raw list outout:

```
dataset[GroupBy["City"] /* "FANNINGSPRINGS", All, "Adjacent_County"] // Normal
```

> `{"GILCHRIST", "LEVY"}`

You can also simply select by the "City" field:

```
ds[Select[#City == "FANNINGSPRINGS" &], "Adjacent_County"]
```

Comment: Thank you Carl!  I accept your answer.

Comment: Happy to help. To accept an answer, click the checkmark underneath the vote counter on the left :)

Answer (score 2):

```
dataset[Select[#[[3]] == "FANNINGSPRINGS" &]]
```

Comment: You could also use the key here: `ds[Select[#City == "FANNINGSPRINGS" &]]` - or if the key has spaces you can quote it like ``ds[Select[#"Key With Space" == "FANNINGSPRINGS" &]]``